# Obtener lista Array con JSON en android studio

Tags: java, android, json, array

tengo un problema que me lleva varias horas fastidiando.

Tengo un dialog que se basa en notificar si existe una nueva version de la aplicacion y manda un mensaje con la versión disponible junto con los cambios en ella.

**Tengo este codigo:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static  String url = "laruta/version.json";
String VersionUpdate;
String Cambios;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new VersionCheck().execute();
}
private class VersionCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        if (jsonStr != null){
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray obtener = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Obtener");
                for (int i = 0; i < obtener.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject v = obtener.getJSONObject(i);
                    VersionUpdate = v.getString("version");
                    Cambios = v.getString("cambios");
                }
            }catch (final JSONException e) {

                // Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "El formato de JSON esta errado: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {



            //Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "El servidor de comprobar versión esta caido.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
        return null;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Void result){

        if (VersionUpdate != null) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String VersionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
        if (VersionUpdate.equals(VersionName)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Version actual: " + VersionName,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Actualización");
            builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            builder.setMessage("Nueva versión disponible" + "\n" + "Incluye: " + Cambios + "\n" + "Version disponible: " + VersionUpdate)
                    .setPositiveButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            final String appName = getPackageName();

                            try {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appName)));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appName)));
                            }

                            finish();

                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Y tengo el formato JSON en una web para poder leerlo este seria:**

```html
{
"Obtener": [
   {
   "version": "1.2",
 "cambios": [ 
   "fox1",
   "fox2",
   "fox3",
   "fox4",
   "fox5",
   "fox6",
   "fox7",
   "fox8",
   "fox9",
   "fox10"
   ]
 }
] 
}
```

**Todo va bien!** sin embargo hay una lectura del json no es la adecuada y me lanza este mensaje así:

[image]

Donde observamos en el formato JSON esta el array "cambios" con una lista fox1 fox2 ...

entonces no hace la lectura correctamente pues sale toda la lista en una sola linea junto con "" y las , por lo que deberia de solo mostrar la lista separadas por lineas sin "" y , ejemplo:

```
Nueva version disponible
Incluye:
Fox1
Fox2
Fox3
Fox4
Fox5
Fox6
Fox7
Fox8
Fox9
Fox10
Versión disponible: 1.2
```

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edito 06/05/2018.**

Ya está resuelto el problema, fui a preguntar en la pagina en ingles de esta misma. En un futuro quizas otra persona este buscando esta solucion, aca está:

> That is because you are casting a JSONArray into a String object. you
>   should do the following to properly format JSONArray to String
>
> ```
> Cambios = "";
> JSONArray cambiosArr = v.getJSONArray("cambios");
> for (int j = 0; j < cambiosArr.length(); j++) {
>     Cambios += cambiosArr.getString(j) + "\n";
> }
> ```
>
> instead of your following line
>
> ```
> Cambios = v.getString("cambios");
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

primero debes crear un modelo del objeto de acuerdo al objeto JSON, por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Obtener {
private String version;

private List<String> cambios = null;


public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

public List<String> getCambios() {
return cambios;
}

public void setCambios(List<String> cambios) {
this.cambios = cambios;
}

}
```

Luego usas la instancia del JSON para recuperar el objeto completo me baso en la clase mensionada: "Obtener":

yo utilizo esta libreria: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1

si lo quieres agregar en build.gradle seria:
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Obtener resultado=gson.fromJson(json,Obtener.class);
```

Esto te da el objeto como tal el cual puedes recuperar los datos que desees, por ejemplo si solo quiero obtener la version seria:

```
Log.i("version",resultado.getVersion());
```

si quiero recorrer la lista de los canales que tu tienes seria:

```
for (String canal: resultado.getcambios()){
 //hago lo que quiera con cada canal, toast o Dialog
}
```

Comment: Conseguí hacerlo sin embargo trate de usar tu metodo y ni por ahi logre hacer nada xD. Sin embargo como comente, logre hacerlo con un for, sin embargo en la variable siempre se guarda el ultimo listado que seria: fox10, mi pregunta es, como ir guardando los valores a una sola variable y que esta los almacene en forma de listado.